# Sometimes text does not render in React-vega Word Cloud

Tags: word-cloud, vega

I am displaying a word cloud of comma separated values using React Vega. Font size range used in the spec is `"fontSizeRange": [30,200]`. However sometimes the text crosses the boundaries of the chart area and its font-size becomes 0. Hence it does not render in the cloud. This occurs randomly, but is not an expected behaviour as it displays empty cloud despite having single phrase data. The problem is solved when I reduce the font size, let's say to `[30,60]`. However with such a smaller range, when number of phrases is huge, all the phrases appear to have same font-size nearly. How to handle these scenarios, is there a way we can display the phrases all the time (font size should never become 0) ?

I have shared my spec in the below URL. After reloading the editor 5-6 times, please observe that sometimes the text is visible in the cloud, while sometimes it's not.

[Link of spec in Vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4KABBBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxkogLvgA6xYD0ZAbsgOboB0NAlvogK4BG9TA9mQigxVa6KgFZ6AK1g8AdpAA04KOjb4esJgC9k2MMFz4AnkV05IRdABNFuAE7JNOvfjttkYAL5KIuAO5MVqx6ABwADGE+UChMNAR6ACwRUbiWVlZMsjR6kcq4Vuj4mDgA2qC+vpCy6KhmhugcADa6KZWU6I3usHolIJCFRUi1svhgAGZMzQpgA+hDyCPjk7p5vgC6rVCu6LKwYzx2qD3lFadbJnWQ8DxsI5aEyHbym2e4E8iNNuYFRYqrr7h4OhYJc2ERTHY-gCKhYBo95OYABQAHWRsAAVCjkX4ANQASlRGLx6Kh0KgsHURD8Bys3SRTAAPrUmUYWSDGmMGX5kAy2LAGTc7AK2HZ+YL2dR+UYbgzpSLZeKFSL2Zy5aKPpKGSgtUxUDr+YhdSqGbBtSgheaDY9jSwGSx+faPpzWMhWS69S6mELPaKGe6JY4uYhCkGmEggzwI3q-IgNDzWEx+awQy6QX7Y2manb+egHFzgVzHjyOMXkAsGSXMjQtehqDWDdYa5QqwyrJG24GMlZWzwWwFGo0uTdPibY2wR0DZAzruPuzc4vg7QByPVypd5lBL-mm5Bbu34Pfc9fxlBGY-LutrutHusus91phL7tr7ub7s7p+Fz93z+PgdKpd-03f8P3-I9-x-f9E1kJdF1zBZYPzWAYMXbkHBQ+sMODagsOsDCO2QxC23wwIMOpMjhysDDTR2RDTUojDJ0QydZB4RcZ0+DDUD5fAMOaA8k2DASI0PIS93NXdBKLUSEP5GNpLkxAzwNHg-D3dAGR2dMeR2bsODUO1OQOCtkCBPkdP5W58EmUNmgFTkQw4Vl9iFAJWE0jgbjguhMgpEz8G5ctMnUdM7HnRBWxFFsSxcnSxnwR4PJ4OsS0aVS-UjMYwr1MFeSIOQez8KdMmFRcCp4MYjOoIVbisRL0B8qcxhFF1vRQKc5HgHkJO0vN5KneS+qUrV0o6QcdlZTz3OQOYIrGZA-CZA4eVQDQytak0eGZWA2HDViGVYoVWLK2RGlZVSp1gGoeRkdMtPUSNqtZK7nvQIxt3QQJRzGvFIH+CpvH+3wTjJSBjFMPRIBc7jGkwF4zn6OlcB2GhmlJUHkAADyISFzBKABaBIxGmSIwCJtYSgAP0pxE7F0rbETxMB0TAABmPE1j+6FAehEHoTBi5Ieh8c4aB05Ech7lYnieHxaxnHIaYMZER+NhUHoBLMfwABebWlwANQAUQAcQAQSXaYADZkjZiJfrFrx-rWPJPA2PJIAQDpHGOf6qmuyHrjSyEXgFiHzBpTIOnRyo2wwTI9D58WfmKeomhaB2oaYD4vkMLH8C504efFumsjqXp+YAYktktWYATjEaPxYrgAxMRa9ZsRDcbmEK-b+va4AdgLipnd8V2UkgDA7AAayRspffBy5NfzkOsq2hOM+TyGijT4ex5DhZrjqjf+YWBLcf0B3KmXk+yRhd5Pm3vO94BIvQY6WIEUvu+YXaTpLi6iMR4L9Xhv35hwYEHxMh1ETqDP+7hIYdCIMGEs1l4AgLOGAgEmcBy3x-rgT2aNzCBwON3fmD8c5g2flfCAngHZYJhGCH4MCaFvEmI0AA8pYeALAjB4J-pAeBdQACMrC6Hc1lrgWM1V+HYImAOLhcxeGyLgR0BBOAwj0DEGI+h-0GFgxLnsA4RxSiwOvoLcw1I7BWHgGlNgNhJEe20GXcIpMkhhDdvzG+OAzHiwoU-LWGDaGOLCkUBKKiEb+O+IUNW9AUZo3oY4-YIxIYAAkNTIDQegMAAA5ZA7hpimzsEwKOSS5D4AAMrOIiX4rOj9on4FiTOFJiSM7JPwAAdWQNLfOPjWGZ2zpDVW6spYLiCV4MpIwqk6AAEoozLqzSIAAmCInjsFpAyFkHIejR60Odp4IAA)

Comment: I think the issue is that with the rotations, sometimes, the text may not be able to fit into the chart area. Can you reduce the font size?

Comment: @dominik yes it does appear when we reduce the font-size, but then if we have more words, then all of them have the same font-size nearly, which defies the word cloud  layout. Ideally the word cloud should show the font size based on the count, right ? But if we provide a smaller range, won't all the words have similar sizes ?